# Max Subscribers Returned (and duplicates) | YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, duplicates, max

[Problem 1]

I am using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list for a large channel (1 million subscribers) but after 100 successful pages of results (50 subscribers per page), the API always returns 0 subscribers.

Is there a hard limit of 100 pages or 5,000 subscribers that can be returned?

[Problem 2]

Of the 5,000 Subscribers returned, only 3,577 are unique. The API seems to be returning duplicates in some cases which I know is a long standing issue with getting channel subscribers. Hoping to learn if this will be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide the HTTP request or code you used to get the list of subscribers?

Comment: Hi - the same exact code works the first 100 times through the loop. After the 100th time it fails. This is the response I get back after 100 times. It gives me a NextPage token but each time we try to retrieve the next page after 100, it returns 0 results: http://content.screencast.com/users/SharedDocs/folders/Jing/media/ce7d19a9-bf5d-4ce2-a240-17f0d1d7ff6f/2015-09-28_1413.png

Comment: Could you try using your code to check the max subscribers for a channel that has less subscribers, for example, around 3000, then again for a channel that has around 5000?

Comment: I experience the same situation with a 1000 limit with duplicates. It does not matter if I use order=[alphabetically,unread] it returns duplicates without order.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the second problem today and it seems like the duplicates happens because the [default order of the API list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#order) is `SUBSCRIPTION_ORDER_RELEVANCE`

Acceptable values are:

```
alphabetical – Sort alphabetically.
relevance – Sort by relevance.
unread – Sort by order of activity.
```

So setting order to be `alphabetical` solves the problem entirely.